# Show that there is no holomorphic function satisfying $f^2(z)=z$

Tags: complex-analysis

I know several ways that show such an $f$ cannot be continuous (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113876/why-is-there-no-continuous-square-root-function-on-mathbbc)). But is there a way to obtain the "weaker" statement that no such function can be holomorphic without proving it can't be continuous?

Comment: $f(0)=0$. Therefore $f(z)=zg(z)$ for some $g$ analytic. then $f^2(z)=z^2g^2(z)=z$. Hence $g^2(z)=\frac{1}{z}$. If $g$ is analytic, so is $g^2$. Contradiction.

Comment: Alternatively, notice that $f(0)=0$ and $|f(z)| \leq 1$ for $|z|<1$. If $f$ is holomorphic, by the Schwarz lemma, this implies $|f(z)|\leq|z|$ for $|z|<1$, from which we easily derive a contradiction.

Comment: BTW [the very first answer from the link you provided](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113876/why-is-there-no-continuous-square-root-function-on-mathbbc/113914#113914) contains a short proof for holomorphic functions: if $f^2(z) = z$ then differentiating at $z=0$ yields $0 = 2 f(0) f'(0) = 1$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure. If such function existed, we would have $f(0) = 0$, so

$$f(z) = a_1 z + a_2 z^2 + a_3 z^3 + \ldots$$

in some open neighbourhood of $0$. But then $$g(z) = a_1 + a_2 z + a_3 z^2 + \ldots$$ would be a function holomorphic in the same neighbourhood, satisfying $f(z) = z \cdot g(z)$. That gives $z = f^2(z) = z^2 g^2(z)$ and therefore $g^2(z) = \frac{1}{z}$, which is unbounded in the neighbourhood of $0$. That is a contradiction.