# Alternate proof that there is no square root function in C

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm looking for a proof that there is no holomorphic function $g: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $g(z)^2 = z$ using the Cauchy Integral Formula.

The same question was asked here [Why is there no continuous square root function on $\mathbb{C}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113876/why-is-there-no-continuous-square-root-function-on-mathbbc) but I am looking for a proof using the CIF. Also I did not understand the second answer: "Start at $z=1$, compute $\sqrt{z}$ as you move around the origin on a circle of radius 1, and look at what happens when you get back to $z=1$."

Answer (score 1):

Wlog $g(1)=1$. 
Assume $\Re g(z)=0$ for some $z\in S^1$. Then $z=g(z)^2\in(-\infty,0]$, i.e., $z=-1$. By continuity, $\Re g(z)>0$ for all $z\in S^1\setminus\{-1\}$.
 Then $$\Re\oint_{S^1}g(z)\,\mathrm dz=\oint_{S^1}\Re g(z)\,\mathrm dz>0,$$
whereas Cauchy's Integral Theorem says $\oint_{S^1}g(z)\,\mathrm dz=0$.

Comment: Am I missing something here? Why is the integral over $S^{1}$ of a positive function positive? Isn't the integral of $1$ over $S^{1}$ zero?