# Does the function $\sqrt{z}=|z|^{1/2} e^{i\frac{Arg(z)}{2}}$ extend continuously on $(-\infty, 0)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

Generally, $z\mapsto Arg (z)\in (-\pi,\pi]$ is not a continuous function on $(-\infty ,0]$. However, we can extend it continuously on $(-\infty,0)$ by making a correction on the definition of the function on the left open complex plane as
$$f(z)=Arg(z),\ z=x+iy, x<0, y\geq 0 $$ and $$f(z)=Arg(z)+2\pi,\  z=x+iy, x<0, y< 0 .$$
So, I was wodering if the function $$z\mapsto \sqrt{z}=|z|^{1/2} e^{i\frac{Arg(z)}{2}}$$ can extend continuously on $(-\infty,0)$ exactly as  $z\mapsto Arg (z)$. I thought to make a correction only on the left open complex plane as
$$g(z)=\sqrt{z}, \ z=x+iy, x<0, y\geq 0 $$ anfd $$g(z)=-\sqrt{z},\ z=x+iy, x<0, y<0 .$$
Eventually, g is a continuous function on $(-\infty,0)$. What can I say now about the continuity of $g$ on $\mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty,0)$? Is it possible the previous trick destroyed the continuity of $\sqrt{z}$ over $\mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty,0)$? Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you are talking about the argument; your extension breaks continuity on the positive real axis; however you do it, you need to exclude a curve connecting zero to infinity (eg a ray) to have a continuous argument; same with the square root, you can define it continuously on the negative axis but you lose continuity somewhere else

Comment: So, the Argument I defined previously is not continuous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define $\sqrt z$ that way, then, since $\operatorname{Arg}(-1)=\pi$, you have $\sqrt{-1}=\exp\left(\frac{\pi i}2\right)=i$. But$$\lim_{\theta\to-\pi}\sqrt{e^{i\theta}}=\lim_{\theta\to-\pi}\exp\left(\frac{i\theta}2\right)=\exp\left(-\frac{\pi i}2\right)=-i.$$Therefore, the answer is negative.

Comment: Wait a second, I know that $\sqrt{z}$ is not continuous on $(-\infty,0)$ so I extended it by defining $g(z)$ as previous. Now $g$ is continuous over $(-\infty, 0)$. Especially at your answer it should be $\displaystyle \lim_{\theta\to-\pi}g(e^{i\theta})=\displaystyle\lim_{\theta\to-\pi}\left(-\exp\left(\frac{i\theta}2\right)\right)=-\exp\left(-\frac{\pi i}2\right)=i,$ which agree with $\sqrt{-1}=i$.

Comment: I do not understand your definition of $g$, but there is *no way* of defining a continuous argument function from $\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$ into $\Bbb R$.

Comment: If I define as an argument function 
$$f(z)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
Arg(z) & , & Re(z)<0, Im(z)\geq 0 \\ 
Arg(z)+2\pi & , & Re(z)<0, Im(z)<0 
\end{matrix}\ ,\right. $$ and $$f(z)=Arg(z)$$ for all $z\in H$, which $$ H=\{z\in \mathbb{C}: Re(z)>0\}$$, then $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$.
Note: $Arg(z)$ is the classic argument as we know

Comment: Since $f$ is defined only when $\operatorname{Re}(z)\ne0$, I fail to see how can you claim that it is defined on $\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: It is  continuous only on the left  semi plane, you have right

Comment: Something final. Can you answer me please why I cannot extend it over $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$? Thanks

Comment: You shall find an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113876/why-is-there-no-continuous-square-root-function-on-mathbbc).

Comment: Surely $Arg(z)$ cannot extend over ${0}$, because $\displaystyle\lim_{z\to 0} Arg(z)$ does not exist. Also, I imagine that whenever I make a correction of continuity the continuity of $Arg(z)$ break somewhere else. Thanks I appreciate!!

Answer (score 0):

Your correction leads to discontinuities on the negative $y$-axis. From the left we now approach $3\pi/2,$ from the right things are unchanged and we approach $-\pi/2.$ There's no way to avoid the $2\pi$-hiccup!